# JNA return char*

Tags: java, jna

how to work with Check type char*? (Check fill in function and contains text >500 characters or pointer on memory with text)

I have my_dll.dll. Description dll

```
int my_function(char* param1, struct answer* ans);

#pragma pack(1)
struct answer{
  int TType;                   //IN
  unsigned long Amount;   //IN
  char          Rcode   [2+1];  //OUT
  char          AMessage[16 ]; //OUT
  int           CType;              //OUT
  char*         Check;            //OUT
};
```

In Java I have code:

```
 public interface My_Dll extends Library {
        public static class answer extends Structure {
                    public static class ByReference extends answer 
                             implements Structure.ByReference {}

              public int  TType      = 0;                   
              public int  Amount     = 0;        
              public byte Rcode[]    = new byte[3]; //OUT: 
              public byte AMessage[] = new byte[16]; //OUT: 
              public int  CType      = 0;         //OUT: 
              public ??? Check;         //OUT: 
              protected List getFieldOrder() {
                      return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"TType", "Amount", 
                             "Rcode","AMessage", "CType","Check"});
              }
        }
        public int my_function(byte track2[], answer.ByReference ans);
  }

  public static void Start() {
      My_Dll test_dll = (My_Dll) Native.loadLibrary("my_dll", My_Dll.class);
      My_Dll.answer.ByReference aa = new My_Dll.answer.ByReference();
      //  In
      aa.Amount = 100;
      aa.TType =3;

      int result = test_dll.my_function(null,aa);
      //  OUT
      System.out.println("Result: "  + result);
      System.out.println("Rcode: "  + new String(aa.Rcode));
      System.out.println("Amessage: " + new String(aa.AMessage));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've tried is to use a pre-constructed array of byte, and then use `Native.toString(...)` to convert it to a Java String. For example,

```
byte[] windowText = new byte[SOME_CONSTANT];
user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, SOME_CONSTANT);
String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();
```

In the code above, 512 worked well as my SOME_CONSTANT, but you will probably need to use a larger constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Check` field must be of pointer type.  If you declare it as `Pointer`, you can use [`Pointer.getString(0)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getString%28long%29) to extract the `String` value.

If it is up to the caller to allocate the memory, you can use `com.sun.jna.Memory` to initialize it; if not, you will need to release the memory returned in the struct to avoid a leak.

Comment: I have tried so:        public static class auth_answer extends Structure {
                    public static class ByReference extends auth_answer implements Structure.ByReference {} ... public Pointer Check; ...}  System.out.println("Check: " + aa.Check.getString(0));

Comment: Error: Unexpected Signal : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) occurred at PC=0x77C378AC
Function=strlen+0xC
Library=C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCRT.dll

Current Java thread:
 at com.sun.jna.Native.getString(Native Method)
 at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getString(Pointer.java:689)
 at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getString(Pointer.java:717)
 at test.JNATestClass.StartPinpad(JNATestClass.java:110)
 at test.JNATestClass.main(JNATestClass.java:166)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0040B000  C:\soft\JDeveloper\jdk1.4\bin\javaw.exe...